# Grails 3, Spring Security Rest username after login

Tags: grails, spring-security, spring-security-rest

I have a Grails 3 application with Spring Security Rest implemented, I can authenticate from my Angular2 app successfully, and with @Secured() applied to the controllers can control which areas of the application can be accessed. So given this,  I know that the authentication and authorization is working.

I'm trying to retrieve the logged in user's username that was used to authenticate.

I've tried `Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()`
 it's null.

I tried
`Principal principal = request.getUserPrincipal()`
it's also null.

Here's my application.groovy

```
    grails.plugin.springsecurity.providerNames = ['customADAuthProvider']
    grails.plugin.springsecurity.successHandler.alwaysUseDefault = true
    grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'User'
    grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'UserRole'
    grails.plugin.springsecurity.authority.className = 'Role'
    grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
        [pattern: '/',               access: ['permitAll']],
        [pattern: '/error',          access: ['permitAll']],
        [pattern: '/index',          access: ['permitAll']],
        [pattern: '/index.gsp',      access: ['permitAll']],
        [pattern: '/shutdown',       access: ['permitAll']],
        [pattern: '/assets/**',      access: ['permitAll']],
        [pattern: '/**/js/**',       access: ['permitAll']],
        [pattern: '/**/css/**',      access: ['permitAll']],
        [pattern: '/**/images/**',   access: ['permitAll']],
        [pattern: '/**/favicon.ico', access: ['permitAll']]
    ]

    grails.plugin.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [
        [pattern: '/assets/**',      filters: 'none'],
        [pattern: '/**/js/**',       filters: 'none'],
        [pattern: '/**/css/**',      filters: 'none'],
        [pattern: '/**/images/**',   filters: 'none'],
        [pattern: '/**/favicon.ico', filters: 'none'],
        [pattern: '/api/**',         filters: 'JOINED_FILTERS,-anonymousAuthenticationFilter,-exceptionTranslationFilter,-authenticationProcessingFilter,-securityContextPersistenceFilter,-rememberMeAuthenticationFilter']
]

    grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.logout.endpointUrl = '/api/logout'
```

No matter what I try, I can never get the authentication object or principal object to retrieve the username or any user details.

I'm using `spring-security-rest:2.0.0.RC1`, and `Grails 3.3.6`

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this...

```
class SomeController {

    def springSecurityService

    def someAction() {
        def user = springSecurityService.currentUser
            // ...
    }
}
```

Or this...

```
class SomeController {

    def springSecurityService

    def someAction() {
        def principal = springSecurityService.principal
        String username = principal.username
        def authorities = principal.authorities // a Collection of GrantedAuthority
        boolean enabled = principal.enabled
        // ...
    }
}
```

Both of those are pasted directly from https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/3.2.x/index.html